# Changing CLion's background color

Tags: clion

I'd like to change the general background color of CLion (that is, outside of where you write code), but I have been unable to find a solution neither in the IDE itself nor online.

However, changing these colors should be possible, as switching the color theme does change them.

Here is an image of what I mean, I've marked the respective areas I would like to change the color of with a bright pink circled x:

[image: Demonstration]

Any help on where I could find these settings would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I already know where to change Fonts, text colors and the like, but I am looking specifically for the marked areas, changes for which do not appear under any of the Color Scheme Options.

Comment: Please change preference. (Theme, Interface color)

Comment: @Alexander I've found where you can change the theme, but do not appear to have an option to alter the interface color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot customize the colors of the main interface except for choosing the Default and Darcula themes in `Appearance and Behavior - Appearance`. What your and the other answer's screenshot shows are the EDITOR color scheme settings.

You can set a background image for the whole IDE in general in that settings tab, though. Make it completely opaque, the color you like, and that might do it.

Answer (score 1):

**To configure colors and fonts**

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or choose **`File | Settings`** (for Windows and Linux) or **`CLion | Preferences`** (for macOS) from the main menu, and then go to Editor | Font.
2. Select the desired scheme from the Scheme name drop-down list.
3. Under the Color Scheme node, define the font families used in the editor and in the console. When you open the Font page, or Console Fonts under the Color Scheme node, CLion displays the Editor Font area where you can configure the primary and secondary fonts, their size and line spacing.

[image]

4. Under the Color Scheme node, open the corresponding pages to configure specific color preferences for the supported languages and CLion components.

---

**To navigate to the relevant Colors & Fonts settings for the symbol at the caret**

1. Call **Help | Find** Action from the main menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and choose Jump to Colors and Fonts:

[image]

2. Explore the relevant section of the **Colors & Fonts** settings for the symbol under the caret:

[image]

---

If you want to know more about configurations : [Configuring Colors and Fonts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html)

Comment: To select the all background, CLion 2020 for Mac: Preferences->Editor->Color Scheme->General->Text->Default text-> Select Background edit box, enter RGB . Not easy to find